# How to create a table with name as parameter?

Tags: c#, razor, sql-server-ce, webmatrix

I don't find in documentation on msdn, how to insert to execute statement a parameter of table name. By parity of reasoning I tried:

```
var myNameOfTable = "wantedName";
db.Execute("CREATE TABLE @0 (id int IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY, data ntext, dataOfAdd datetime)", myNameOfTable);
```

But I get error:

> [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 14,Token in error = @0 ]

Please help me - how to create table with name as parameter?

Comment: try using [String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

Comment: @Danil, just because you can, doesn't mean you should...

Comment: Just because you can but you shouldn't.. Then if you need to then how to for the sole purpose of avoiding SQL Injection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are giving table name through options, instead using *string concatenation/string.Format* to make the query. You at least use [Paramerized Query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163799.aspx#S5) or better use stored procedure instead of inline query as they could result in [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You can read this post [Stored procedures vs. inline SQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44544/stored-procedures-vs-inline-sql) for comparison.

```
db.Execute("CREATE TABLE " + myNameOfTable + " (id int IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY, data ntext, dataOfAdd datetime)" );
```

The syntax you are using could be achieved using [string.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
db.Execute(string.Format("CREATE TABLE {0} (id int IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY, data ntext, dataOfAdd datetime)", myNameOfTable));
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd agree that I'd rather use legitimate parameters here. You could create a stored procedure that you pass in a table name to, something like this comes to mind:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_CreateTable
    @TableName VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @SqlScript NVARCHAR(4000)
    SET @SqlScript = 'CREATE TABLE ' + @TableName + ' (ID INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL)'

    EXEC sp_executesql @SqlScript

END
```

Comment: Disclaimer: I despise dynamic SQL and I would avoid this, and whatever you're trying to accomplish above with the string.Format, like the plague!

Comment: So can somebody explain to me how this AVOIDS SQL Injection? I can still inject whatever I need in the table name on the SPROC correct?