# Sql Parameterized query for creating tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

Trying to create SQL tables in ado.net with code. I've been using the parameterized query to create the table which works but im also getting an second table with the name @name which is obvious because im passing it too. Now my question is how do i prevent the table creating of @name ?

Here is my query

```
public void CreateTable(string name)
        {
            string connectionString = @"Data Source=tcp:SRV-SKYSPARK,1434;Initial Catalog=Trevi-NV;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False";
            string query =
                @"CREATE TABLE [dbo].[@name] (
                [Id]          INT         IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
                [TimeStamp]   DATETIME    NOT NULL,
                [TagName]     NCHAR (64)  NOT NULL,
                [Value]       NCHAR (32)  NOT NULL,
                [TagType]     NCHAR (64)  NULL,
                [Description] NCHAR (128) NULL
                );";
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = name;
                cn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cn.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/28598876/18452174

Comment: Thats not working for me.

Comment: Parameters work only for values, not identifiers.

Comment: Whats the best way to do it ?

Comment: If you replace @name with {0}, use string.Format to set the name in the query string and remove the use of Parameters, it must work.

Comment: Alright, it's working thanks! forgot the {0}.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a table with name as parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28598828/how-to-create-a-table-with-name-as-parameter)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A table name as a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838490/a-table-name-as-a-variable)

Comment: @Victor That doesn't provide the protection against SQL injection offered by [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql). Nor does having square brackets around the inserted string.

Comment: @HABO You'r right! I wasn't thinking about an attack. I had assumed that the creation of the table is under his control, not as a parameter obtained from the user that he need to validate.

Comment: Try this Nuget library to simplify Ado.net code  : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ado.Entity